# bash script to gzip files

Tags: bash, gzip

I have to make a bash script that do a gzip of a file if is older than 60 days, and move it in a subdir which name is the beginning of the filename. Here an example of the files I have to work with:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 X X    0 2012-10-15 11:19 glux21-x1.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 X X    0 2012-10-15 11:19 GLUX21-x34.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 X X    0 2012-10-15 11:19 glux226.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 X X    0 2012-10-15 11:19 glux228.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 X X    0 2012-10-15 11:19 glux230.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 X X    0 2012-10-15 11:19 glux232.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 X X    0 2012-10-15 11:19 glux234.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 X X    0 2012-10-15 11:19 glux236.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 X X    0 2012-10-15 11:19 glux255.csv
```

So, for example, the glux21-x1.csv should be gzipped and moved in the glux21 subdir, as for the GLUX21-x34.csv file. The glux255.csv should go in the glux255 subdir.

Comment: My advice, get some code together, test it. If you have any troubles someone will help you. But don't expect us to do your homework ;)

Comment: Do you know [`logrotate`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)?  It could do a lot of what you're after and is flexible (eg. with the `lastaction` directive).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -ctime -60 -maxdepth 1 -type f | while IFS= read x
 do 
    gzip -9 "$x"  # compress it
    D=${x%%.csv}  
    D=${D/-*/}    # remove suffix and everything after the -

    mkdir -p "$D" # create dest sub folder
    mv $x.gz "$D"   # move it
done
```

This will process all files you needed, and put them into different sub folder respectly.

Comment: I don't think that the above will handle the situation where special characters (such as spaces) are present in the filename.